# Can not understand Piecewise Function Problem with floor and ceiling

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|\lfloor{x}\rfloor| &\text{if }x\text{ is rational}, \\
\lceil{x}\rceil^2 &\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}.
\end{cases}$$

Find $f(\sqrt[3]{-8})+f(-\pi)+f(\sqrt{50})+f\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)$

I am overall very confused on how to solve it. Is it really as hard as it looks or am I missing an easy to way to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you know what are the functions floor and ceiling? If so, you just need to check which of the arguments given are rational and which are irrational and then take its floor or its ceiling and do the summation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take it in pieces

$\sqrt[3] {-8} = -2$ is rational

$f(-2) = |\lfloor -2 \rfloor | = | -2 | = 2$

$-\pi$ is irrational

$f(-\pi) = \lceil -\pi \rceil^2 = (-3)^2 = 9$

etc.

Comment: So it is really that easy?

Comment: we have gone from "is it really as hard as it looks" to "is it really that easy" in 5 minutes.  not bad.

Comment: So is the final answer 56.5 + π^2?

Comment: no $f(x)$ always returns an integer.  So the answer must be an integer,

Comment: Oops. I totally forgot about floor and ceiling. So is the answer 72?

Comment: 2 + 16+ 64 + 4 = 86. I forgot about the ceiling on the sqrt50

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61268/discussion-between-houdineo-and-doug-m).

Comment: You forgot the the π is negative. So the ceiling would actually be -3. So instead of 16, it would be 9.

Comment: good call 2 + 9 + 64 + 4 = 79